# Is there a way to filter pending txs?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, pending-transactions

I wrote a script to track unconfirmed transactions in the mempool, but my script is always triggered by txs, that are too long pending for like many hours or days because of not enough gas that was spended. I cannot use those txs, so is there any way to filter pending txs in the mempool, to only get my script triggered by pending txs that are only for 1sec or so in the mempool. I dont find a solution because there is no timestamp created yet :(